# Prove a point inside a regular hexagon will divide it to two different areas

Tags: geometry, area

Given a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ and a point $P$ inside it, prove
$$S_{PAB}+S_{PCD}+S_{PEF}=S_{PBC}+S_{PDE}+S_{PAE}$$
so it creates two trios of triangles.

all the sides of the hexagon are equal, so it comes down to showing
$$h_a+h_c+h_e=h_b+h_d+h_f$$
and I know
$$h_a+h_d=h_b+h_e=h_c+h_f=H$$
where $H$ is the height of the hexagon.

Any idea on how to begin? (a hint or a direction)

Comment: Try to use the symmetry - rotations of $\pi /3$

Comment: @Moti I found the solution already, I showed the heights of a point inside an equilateral triangle is the height of the triangle, then there are two triangles that inscribe the hexagon and form a 6-point star. thus, $h_a+h_c+h_e=h_b+h_d+h_f$.

Comment: This relation is true for every Even side equilateral polygon. Symmetry allow you to extend the solution without the need to calculate heights - directly areas.

Comment: @Moti yes, I saw it is true for every even numbered polygon, although it is way easier to show it for ones with ones divisible by 4.

Answer (score 1):

the lines $AB$,$CD$,$EF$ form one equilateral triangle. lines $BC$,$DE$,$FA$ form the other. Then I can easiely show $h_a+h_c+h_e=h_b+h_d+h_f$ since the sum of heights from a point inside an eqilateral triangle to all sides is the height of the triangle.